# Thread in each item of gridview

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-progressbar

I have implemented a **Horizontal scrolling Gridview**. I want a **Horizontal ProgressBar** in each item so I am binding a thread with each item in **getView** of adapter. The problem is that when I scroll my gridview, the progressbar in some items show strange behaviour and sometimes some of them swap their position. I know that **View** in gridview **Recycles** and I have tackled that thing but still binding thread in getView is causing problem.

**Adapter**

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_grid_now_playing, null);
            // set image based on selected text
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.channel_icon = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.channel_icon);
            holder.progress = (ProgressBar) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.progress);
            holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            holder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.MainLayout);
            holder.progressBar.setMax(Scheduler
                    .getMaxValueOfProgressBar(tvShows.get(position)));

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    end = Scheduler.getMaxValueOfProgressBar(tvShows
                            .get(position));
                    mProgressStatus = Scheduler
                            .getProgressedValueOfProgressBar(tvShows
                                    .get(position));
                    flags[position] = true;
                    while (mProgressStatus < end) {
                        // mProgressStatus += 1;
                        // Update the progressBar bar and display the
                        // current value in the text view
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                mProgressStatus = Scheduler
                                        .getProgressedValueOfProgressBar(tvShows
                                                .get(position));
                                holder.progressBar.setProgress(mProgressStatus);

                            }
                        });
                        try {
                            // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.
                            // Just to display the progressBar slowly
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();

        holder.title.setText(tvShows.get(position).getTv_title());

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First: please consider to use AsynkTask instead of Thread.
Second: inside the handler you have to check if the holder is still binded to that Thread, something like:

```
if(holder.position==position){
    mProgressStatus = Scheduler
        .getProgressedValueOfProgressBar(tvShows
        .get(position));
    holder.progressBar.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
}
```

PS: set `holder.position` right before you create the thread:

```
holder.position=position;
```

Comment: I am updating progressbar at intervals but in case of Async task I can only update the result on UI thread. How can I use Async to move progressbar smoothly? start new Async on onPostExecute ?

Comment: by the way setting position in holder didn't work :(

Comment: In an Asynktask you can notify the UI of the progressChange using publishProgress(); and handle that value by overriding the method onProgressUpdate in the AsynkTask

Comment: I mean nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I partially agree with @Spotlight answer, you should be blindly firing new threads like this. They take time, consume resource, make your scrolling slower.

Also, all your threads is really doing is getting current value from the `Scheduler` and then firing a `new Runnable` to the UI thread and sleeping. So after a very soft fling on your GridView you have a few dozens thread sleeping and firing `new` objects all the time, that's just plain wrong all together. Consider having the view scheduling `Runnables` by calling `postDelayed`. Probably the `Runnable` should belong to the `Holder`.

The reason your views are getting mixed up, is that, even thou you create a `new Thread` and that new thread is binded to the view during the `getView` the old thead that was bind to the same view is still binded to it. It still is calling `setProgress` on **the same view**.

Probably something like this will work better:

```
Holder h;
if(convertView == null){
    // init
} else{
    // grab reference
}

// stop previous calls
holder.progressBar.removeCallbacks(holder.runnable);

// update position
holder.position = position;

// run the update
holder.runnable.run();
```

then this `runnable` inside holder will be something like

```
runnable = new Runnable(){

    public void run() {
        end = Scheduler.getMaxValueOfProgressBar(tvShows.get(position));
        mProgressStatus = Scheduler.getProgressedValueOfProgressBar(tvShows.get(position));

        // re-schedule if nedded
        if(mProgressStatus < end){
            progressBar.postDelayed(holder.runnable, 200);
        }
    }
}
```

that way you guarantee only 1 runnable per view and you don't need to be firing multiple threads for just `sleep(time)`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Though I figured out the problem that I am creating new threads on old threads but could not figured out the way out of it. I should give it a try. I'll get back to you

Comment: can you please update the above code . I did try your solution but still facing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Download the source code and you can use this source code as reference :

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader